# Почему setTimeout выводит unedfined?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f(x) {
 console.log(x)
}

function delay(f, ms) {

  return function() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      f.apply(this, arguments)
    }, ms )
  };

}

let f1000 = delay(f, 1000);
f1000('asd')
```

1. В переменную **f1000**  функция **delay()** вернет **анонимную функцию**
2. Функция **f1000('asd')**  вызывает **setTimeout** в которой первый аргумент стрелочная функция, 2 аргумент время задержки
3. Разберем первый аргумент (стрелочная функция) **setTimeout**  подробнее
4. В стрелочной функции происходит вызов **f.apply(this, arguments)**
5. функция **f** первый аргумент **this** т.к. тут нету объекта то **this** будет равен глобальному объекту **window**
6. функция **f** второй аргумент **arguments** будет браться из анонимной функции т.к. в стрелочной функции нету **this и arguments**
7. Правильно понял **this** ?

```js
function f(x) {
 console.log(x)
}

function delay(f, ms) {

  return function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
      f.apply(this, arguments)
    }, ms )
  };

}

let f1000 = delay(f, 1000);
f1000('asd')
```

Comment: ни один из приведенных примеров не выводит undefined, как они относятся в вопросу _Почему setTimeout выводит unedfined?_

Comment: чем вообще отличаются два блока кода в вопросе кроме форматирования?

Comment: @Grundy 1) второй блок кода выводит undefined; 2) 1блоке коде стрелочная функция и небольшой вопрос про this ; 2блоке анонимная функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Строчка

```
  f.apply(this, arguments)
```

находится внутри функции, у которой нет параметров:

```
setTimeout( function() {
  f.apply(this, arguments)
} )
```

Вызов

```
    f.apply(this, arguments)
```

находится внутри *стрелочной* функции,

```
setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, arguments), ms);
```

у которой `arguments` указывает на контейнер параметров той функции, которая содержит стрелочную.

Comment: посмотрите первый блок кода пожалуйста

Comment: в этом примере setTimeout( function() {
  f.apply(this, arguments)
} ) this будет  указывать на глобальный объект ?

Comment: @user349791 да.